# Не работает псевдоэлемент before

Tags: css, sass, псевдоэлемент

не могу понять, почему не работает before, препроцессор sass

```
&__image
    position: relative
    transform: translate(50%, -50%)
    &::before
       content: ""
       position: absolute
       top: 0
       left: 0
       background-image: url(../img/1/music.png)
       background-size: 136px
       background-repeat: no-repeat
       z-index: 10

<div class="page__screen screen">
              <div
                data-swiper-parallax="50%"
                data-swiper-parallax-duration="1000"
                class="screen__body icon icon-first"
              >
                <div class="icon-first-block">
                  <div class="icon-first-block__image">
                    <img src="img/1/logo.svg" alt="icon: Platano Fest" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="icon-first-block__btn">
                    <button class="button icon-first-block__button">
                      Купить билет
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Что скрывается за `&` ?

Comment: Скорее всего icon-first-block

Comment: @OliverPatterson: именно! Думаю, что у Вас та же ошибка -  вместо `.icon-first-block` (класс), введено `icon-first-block` (тег). Просто пропущена точка вначале.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Как по мне здесь не хватает ширины и высоты.
   &__image
    position: relative
    transform: translate(50%, -50%)
    &::before
       content: ""
       position: absolute
       top: 0
       left: 0
       width: 100px
       height: 100px
       background-image: url(../img/1/music.png)
       background-size: 136px
       background-repeat: no-repeat
       z-index: 10

<div class="page__screen screen">
              <div
                data-swiper-parallax="50%"
                data-swiper-parallax-duration="1000"
                class="screen__body icon icon-first"
              >
                <div class="icon-first-block">
                  <div class="icon-first-block__image">
                    <img src="img/1/logo.svg" alt="icon: Platano Fest" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="icon-first-block__btn">
                    <button class="button icon-first-block__button">
                      Купить билет
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо)) заработало